# Capture text in the middle of a sentence using R

Tags: regex, r

I have a sentence like below:

`1字樓High Care Level`

I want to extract the term "High Care Level", so I use the following script:

```
> gsub("([A-Z][a-z]+ Care Level).*","\\1","1字樓High Care Level")
[1] "1字樓High Care Level"
```

Why `1字樓` is still there?

Remarks: `1字樓` is some Chinese phrase

Comment: Updated explanation below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1字樓` is still there because you don't match it, therefore you do not replace it.

You need to match the first part of the string then put your replacement text in a back-reference (as you have done). You can *make* this work by anchoring the expression at the start of the string with the `^` and optional capture of *any* number of *any* characters, but any upper or lower case letters that are contiguous with `Care Level` will be matched as back reference 1, and then the rest of the string is matched. You replace the whole string by only what was matched in back reference 1...

```
gsub("^.*([A-Z][a-z]+ Care Level).*","\\1","1字樓High Care Level")
#[1] "High Care Level"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same regular expression with `gregexpr`:

```
xx <- "1字樓High Care Level")
regmatches(xx,gregexpr("[A-Z][a-z]+ Care Level",xx))
[[1]]
[1] "High Care Level"
```